# Solr - How to set a default operator in Solr 6.6?

Tags: solr, solr6

In Solr 6.6 the *defaultOperator* config setting has been deprecated in `managed-schema`

```
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Where should I set it in Solr 6.6?

Comment: use `"q.op"` query parameter while requesting to solr. if default operator is set to AND and if you mention OR with `q.op`. The "q.op" request parameter takes precedence.

Answer (score 7):

As for [vinod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5638172/vinod) suggestion, that parameter can be used at query time with `q.op=OR`, and if you, like me, prefer to have it predefined you can add the value in `solrconfig.xml` itself, in the `/select` requestHandler

In the same file is possible to specify also a `<defaultSearchField>` (also deprecated and removed) with the `df` parameter

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
      will be overridden by parameters in the request
    -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">text_en</str>
        <str name="q.op">OR</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```